# Can't install mysql-client-core* on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, server, apt, xubuntu, mysql

I tried to mysql-client-core* install via apt-get on ubuntu 14 ; but, it was fail .

The following  that is my os:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~/pvz2/pvz2server/dockerfiles$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.4.0-31-generic #50~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jul 13 01:07:32 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

installing infomation:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~/pvz2/pvz2server/dockerfiles$  sudo apt-get install -y mysql-client-core*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.1' for regex 'mysql-client-core*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.5' for regex 'mysql-client-core*'
Note, selecting 'mysql-client-core-5.6' for regex 'mysql-client-core*'
Note, selecting 'virtual-mysql-client-core' for regex 'mysql-client-core*'
mysql-client-core-5.5 is already the newest version.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-client-core-5.6 : Breaks: mysql-client-core-5.5 but 5.5.54-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I use: apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.6 or  mysql-client-core-5.5 , can successfully to install , but don't to connect mysql server .

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -uxxx -pxxx

ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)
```

I hope to install mysql-client-core-5.6 than  mysql-client-core-5.5.

Who can help me ?

Comment: Is there MySQL server installed? `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest running `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get update` to clear old packages lingering on your system, and then updating the sources. Then install the program.